# Conditional Field in Content Type

Tags: entities

I am looking for a module or a method in Drupal 7 that can achieve the following:

I have a field in a content type called e.g. "Is the Ladder Attached".
It has a select list, YES or NO.

When a user selects YES then I want it to populate another field next to it saying "No Hazard".

When a user selects NO then I want it to populate another field next to it saying "Hazard".

How can this be done?  I tried the conditional field module and it doesn't seem to be the right solution.

Thanks

Comment: while trying the same with conditional fields I ended up with https://drupal.org/node/1637466

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [Field Conditional State](https://drupal.org/project/field-conditional-state) module: With field conditional state module you can set #state form field attribute based on value selected in other form fields.

Module splits fields into two types:

- Control field - field which set #state attribute based on the value from that field
- controled field - field for which #state attribute is set based on the value from the control field.

Module supports AND/OR functionality for control fields which means:

- AND - all choices must be selected to control the filed (example: field A will be visible when in field B option 1 and option 2 is selected)
- OR - any choice will control field (example: field A will be visible when in field B option 1 or option 2 is selected).

Answer (score 1):

I think **Conditional Fields** best suits your requirement.

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>       When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.

Follow this https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Comment: or simply you can write some js to show hide a div what conditional fields module does....